# Using json to pass information to my database

Tags: php, json

Can't figure out the issue with why it's not calling my php page that I want to use to add the information to my database.  Here's the js page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var _lname = 'lname';
var _fname = 'fname';
var _mname = 'mname';
var _gender = 'Male';
var _bday = '11/22/1123';
var _ssn = '456123456';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/upload.php",
    data: "{'lastName':'" + _lname + "','firstName':'" + _fname + "','middleName':'" + _mname + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){
        alert("Success!")
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/kowboykit/kowboykit-includes-db.php";

$data = $_POST['data'];
json_decode($data);
$lastname = json_decode($data['lastName']);

$sql= "INSERT INTO `Kowboy_Kit`.`test` (`ID`, `Name`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $lastname . "');";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo $sql;
```

Comment: You do not use json_decode() correctly. Try `$lastname = json_decode($data)['lastName'];`

Answer (score 1):

PHP expects `key=value` data pairs for GET/POST data. You're not sending that. You're sending a bare string (e.g. just `value`), so PHP has nothing to put into $_POST.

Either do

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

or

```
data: "data={'lastName':'" + _lname + "','firstName':'" + _fname + "','middleName':'" + _mname + "'}",
       ^^^^^
```

And note that building json like that is risky. Consider what happens if someone named `Miles O'Brien` comes along - you'll be generating illegal/invalid JSON and the entire json string will be rejected by the JSON parser

Comment: Tried both changes that were recommended and it's still not passing the data, or even calling the .php page.

Comment: I added a handler just to see if the ajax call was even loading the .php page and that seems to be where im stuck at.  Im really just trying to get a handle on passing data form page to page, and I realize it needs to be sanitized, but I really cant figure out why the function isnt calling the php page at all.

Comment: then add an `error` handler to your $.ajax() call, see if that's failing. and note that your php code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and since you have no error handling at all in the DB code, you're just assuming it could never fail (bad bad bad assumption).

Comment: I'm aware of the SQL issues I'm just trying to get the data passing ATM, I plan to structure the query and sanitize the string once I get this working.  At the moment using the recommendation you gave me it is calling the php now but its not sending any data, $_POST['data'] is empty.

Comment: Then do `var_dump($_POST, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`. see what's arriving at the server, and make sure the script is being executed  as POST - far too frequently there's a redirect somewhere that turns the POST into a GET and kills the posted data.

Comment: The entire $_POST is just returning an empty array